# Simple app for running SQL on local files?

Tags: sql

I'm no expert in SQL, but I find the basics I know to be quite useful. I was wondering if you know of a simple tool to run SQL queries localy on csv or Excel file son my computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran into a good one which is exactly what I was looking for: DB Browser for SQLite on the Ubuntu store.

Answer (score 0):

You could use textql : https://github.com/dinedal/textql

You will be able to load a csv file and do sql queries on it.

```
 textql -sql "select * from tbl" -source some_file.csv
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you install SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU, you can run it locally

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [the sqlite3 command line interface](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) which has a pretty quick path to import CSV:

```
.mode csv
.import C:\your\file.csv TABLE_NAME
select * from TABLE_NAME limit 10
```

Assuming you have a header row in the CSV, it will auto-create the table and you can then run any queries you want against it.

For Excel files you'd need to export to CSV beforehand to take this approach.